# pydrive: listFile does not list all files

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I use pyDrive as a communication tool of my classic Python-based GIS and Google Earth Engine (GEE). Therefore, I need to transfer data from Google Drive to my local machine, but I face some problems:

The upload of data works, and I can see uploaded data in a Drive.ListFile command, but I can't neither enter folders by using their ID nor find any folders via listFile.

```
listfile = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
```

Upload and Download of test data works like a charm, but the folders drive me crazy! Is there some kind of refresh of the Drive needed?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include folders in you [Files.list call](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list?refresh=1) use the query

```
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
```

Also don't forget to specify your [field parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list?refresh=1#response).

Comment: Not sure if the API or documentation has changed since this answer was written, but it currently says you should get both files and folders if you don't specify a mimeType. The documentation says to specify that mimeType to return _only_ folders.